# variable value not showing in TextView on app start

Tags: java, android

On opening my app the home page should display 2 values. These values are taken from 2 variables.
The next page also has the same problem, this page has 20 `TextView` fields which should show values from an `ArrayList`

MainActivity.java

```
 package android.example.com.whstracker;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();


//Global variables

    TextView newHcp, exactHcp;
    Button enterBtn;
    public static Float handicap; // global variable
    int hcpInt;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Handicap is " + handicap);

        //Declare views
        enterBtn = findViewById(R.id.inputNew);
        newHcp = findViewById(R.id.currentHcp);
        exactHcp = findViewById(R.id.exactHcp);
        load();
        
        display();

    }

    public void display() {

        try {
            //round up or down to give playing handicap from hcpInt.
            hcpInt = Math.round(handicap);
            //Set the handicap text as the current playing handicap.
            newHcp.setText(Float.toString(hcpInt));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "error" + e);
        }

        try{
            //Format the handicap to show 2dp and show on screen
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
            String exHcp = df.format(handicap);
            exactHcp.setText(exHcp);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Error" + e);
        }

    }

    public void enterNew(View view) {
        //Start new activity to enter new score.
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Calculator.class);
        startActivity(intent);


    }

    public void seeScores(View view) {
        //Show activity which will show the last 20 scores.
        Intent seeScore = new Intent(this, Data.class);
        startActivity(seeScore);

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Array size is " + Calculator.masterList.size());
    }



    private void load() {
        //Load the ArrayList from SharedPreferences
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = sharedPreferences.getString(Calculator.mList, null);
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Integer>>() {}.getType();
        Calculator.masterList = gson.fromJson(json, type);

        if(Calculator.masterList == null) {
            Calculator.masterList = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }
    
    public void calculateSc() {
        // TODO: 11/09/2020 sort out importing handicap and shpwing on main screen.
        ArrayList<Integer> sortList = new ArrayList<>(Calculator.masterList);
        Collections.sort(sortList);

        handicap = (sortList.get(0) + sortList.get(1) + sortList.get(2) + sortList.get(3) + sortList.get(4) + sortList.get(5) + sortList.get(6) + sortList.get(7) / 8f) ;
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "handicap is " + handicap);
    }
    }
```

The next page has similar code for the `onCreate` and then for the method to display the 20 values,

```
s1.setText("Score 1 is " +Integer.toString(Calculator.masterList.get(0)));
```

then repeated for the other 19 `TextViews`

Both the `ArrayList` and the `handicap` variable are saved in `SharedPreferences` each time the values change.

Can anyone help with getting these values to show on app start up.

Comment: Where do You save and load this data from SharedPreferences? If You paste the whole code Your `hendicap` and `hcpInt` should be 0 because You didn't load them

Comment: I have amended the question to show the whole MainActivity class.